# Counting prime histograms

Tags: number-theory

How to count numbers up to N, so that they have a specific prime histogram, e.g.
(1,2,1,1,1) i.e. numbers in form $p \cdot q^2 \cdot r \cdot s \cdot t$, where p,q,r,s,t - primes and $1<p<q<r<s<t<N$.

My idea is to calculate this sum:
$\displaystyle\sum_{p<N^{1/6}} \sum_{p<q<(N/p)^{1/5}} \sum_{q<r<(N/(p \cdot q^2))^{1/3}} \sum_{r<s<(N/(p \cdot q^2 \cdot r))^{1/2}} [\pi(N/(p \cdot q^2 \cdot r \cdot s)) - \pi(s)]$

My question is, can it be done faster, e.g. using some inclusion-exclusion technique?

Comment: Precise count or approximate count?  If approximate, how approximate is good enough?  Only that specific histogram or a general histogram?  What is the range of expected $N$?  ($N > \pi(10^{25})$ will be an unequivocal problem.)

Comment: I need precise count for a general histogram up to $10^{13}$.